# Retrofit 2 - How show progress bar async?

Tags: android, asynchronous, retrofit, progress

I created a default login activity when creating a new project in Android.
By default creates a progressBar that works well to login and displayed correctly. All this makes it through AsyncTask.

Now I used Retrofit 2 to make way Async login.

When I pushed the button login launched a method that content:

```
    ....
    ....
    showProgress(true);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, retrofit2.Response<User> response) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            User userdatos = response.body();

                if(userdatos != null){
                    // redirect to Main Activity page
                    showProgress(false);
                    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                else{
                    showProgress(false);
                    mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
                    mPasswordView.requestFocus();
                }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            call.cancel();
            showProgress(false);
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please check your network connection and internet permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

I forced a Thread.sleep (3000) to check.
No progress bar appears, and the debug shows:
Skipped 180 frames! The application May be doing too much work on ITS main thread.

How can this be solved?

I will have many Async calls where I would always display a progress bar to wait for the response is complete.

Thank you

Comment: You should not call `Thread.sleep()` on the UI thread.

Comment: mmmm.... oki... but:
 since then I simulate that the request takes a couple of seconds? And so to ensure that the progress bar is displayed?

In addition, I thought that making the call with Retrofit 2 so Async, would like AsyncTask.

Comment: I think the problem is with your showProgress implementation or with that call executes so fast, and you are not able to see progress bar, because it was showed/hided immediately. If you add a delay instead of a sleep (handler post) you will see a progress bar.

Comment: Thanks @Beloo, call execute so fast....  O_o. I try add delay with hadlet post, work well

Answer (score 0):

Let me share with you mine code implementation for default Login activity created by Android Studio and my Retrofit implementation. Default login activity, consist `AsyncTask` which called `UserLoginTask`, inside it, I did all my login logic stuff. I am using `.execute` instead of `.enqueue` because it synchronous and we don't need new thread inside `AsyncTask`

```
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        private final String mEmail;
        private final String mPassword;

        UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
            mEmail = email;
            mPassword = password;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Retrofit restAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Constants.ROOT_API_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            IConstructSecureAPI service = restAdapter.create(IConstructSecureAPI.class);
            Call<JsonElement> result = service.getToken(mEmail, mPassword, "password");
            try {
                //using sync request and get response 
                JsonElement element = result.execute().body();
                if(element!=null) {
                    //do whatever you want with your response
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);

            if (success) {
                if(clientType != 2){
                    mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
                    mPasswordView.requestFocus();
                    clientType = 0;
                }
                else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
//                finish();
            } else {
                mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
                mPasswordView.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.

In one of my tests, I did.

But I have a question:
What can be the reason why we want to use Rretrofit 2 Sync with AsyncTask, can use Retrofit 2 Async?
Thank you

Comment: @daicon of course you can, but in your questions I didn't see all your activity code. I don't understand for what you wrote sleep as well. 
In generaly, your question not clear for me, do you have problem with Retrofit or some exceptions with UI or just see warning  "too much work on ITS main thread" ?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Shameless Promotion</sub>

I've created [RxLoading library](https://github.com/ndori/RxLoading) for that, it can do this and much more,

you can just do something like this:

```
networkCall().compose(RxLoading.<>create(loadingLayout)).subscribe(...);
```

it consists out of 2 classes, a custom view (loadingLayout) and RxLoading which is a [transformer](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Implementing-Your-Own-Operators#transformational-operators) that glue it all together, you can choose to work with both or either of them.

you need to be using retrofit2 with RxJava though.

RxLoading also supports empty and error states (with built-in retry mechanism, so make sure to check this options as well)

you can find out more on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/ndori/RxLoading).